# Como inserir imagem no MySQL usando Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estou utilizando java com hibernate e gostaria de saber como faço para inserir uma imagem no banco de dados mysql.

Tenho várias informações sendo persistidas com o hibernate, faltando apenas a imagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que você tenha uma coluna "Imagem" do tipo blob em uma tabela, você precisará definir o tipo de dado na classe do modelo como um array de bytes (byte[]):

```
private byte[] imagem;

...

public byte[] getImagem() {
    return this.imagem;
}

public void setImagem(byte[] imagem) {
    this.imagem = imagem;
}
```

E no arquivo de mapeamento adicionar a propriedade referente à imagem:

```
<property name="imagem" type="binary">
    <column name="imagem" />
</property>
```

Quando for salvar no banco de dados, você, programaticamente, usa o método setImagem.

Para mais informações, há um tutorial (em inglês) aqui:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme.